# Freeradius my custom module to set Framed-IP-Address

Tags: freeradius

I got a complicated schema where my radius server needs to send the 
Framed-IP-Address based on the results of a redis-db query so, I would 
like to know if if the post-auth part of my default config I can do 
that.

Something like (or any other solutions doing this):

```
    update reply { 
            Framed-IP-Address := xxx.xx.xx.xx 
    }
```

where xxx.xx.xx.xx is an ip address returned by a module.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, absolutely.

You can do:

```
update reply {
    Framed-IP-Address := "%{redis: <your redis query>}"
}
```

The server core will take care of converting the ASCII IP address into it's binary form.

And yes, the most efficient place to insert this would be in post-auth.